# Build with PyInstaller skipping libraries

Tags: python, pyinstaller

i'm trying to build an app for windows using PyInstaller, but skipping libraries (ex django). I'm will run requirements.txt to use the installed libaries on local system python.
The intention is to compile (protect) the code and keep the libraries on system.

Saw about changing the python path on runtime using hook, but not found nothing.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude modules on the command line like this:

```
pyinstaller --exclude-module django
```